# VB.NET Webbrowser How to display specified content I want

Tags: vb.net

eg: the source code will be:

```
<html>
<head> balaba....
</head>
<body>
<div id="many_div">...</div>


<div id="main">

     <div id="target">
     .....balabala ...
     </div>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Then, how to let my webbrowser only display the div with "target" id ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to manipulate the HTML of the page.

I would use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract the part you want and rewrite it to the same or another file:

```
Dim html = File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\htmlTest.htm")
Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)
Dim target = doc.GetElementbyId("target")
If target IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body")
    body.RemoveAll()
    body.PrependChild(target)
    Using writer = File.OpenWrite("c:\temp\htmlTest2.htm")
        doc.Save(writer)
    End Using
End If
```

Now you just have to load this html in the `WebBrowser`.

If you want to get the HTML directly from internet/intranet:

```
Dim client As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb()
Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = client.Load("http://yoururl.com")
' rest is the same as above(without doc.LoadHtml) '
```

Comment: Thanks,Tim.
You code may be good.
But one more issue is the html code is come from internet exactly.
Should htmlAgilityPack be able to do that?

Comment: I don't have a try at this moment.
Just wondering in the html there is a CAPTCHA generated inside, after reload html page, the captcha may be changed.

Comment: I finally use   WebBrwoser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(X, Y);  to make the content I want to display in the webbrower center.
But I think the HtmlAgilityPack that @Tim introduce is a good solution too, worth to have a try.Thanks!